# Spring Boot criteria builder to build dynamic query to find the sum of the columns. I may give any number of column names

Tags: spring-boot

```
public Object multiColumn(@RequestBody String column) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(column);
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("column");
    
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> create = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<ItemListing> root = create.from(ItemListing.class);
    create.multiselect(builder.sum(root.get(?)), builder.sum(root.get(?)));
    TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery(create);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I will sent the column names through postman as a JSON array , I need to point out the names inside the array of json to the query builder.
final query query to be created dynamically is
eg:   select sum(price), sum(quantity) from item_listing;

```
"column":["price", "quantity"]
```

This is my POJOclass with all attributes.

```
@Entity(name ="item_listing")
@SQLDelete(sql = "update item_listing set deleted= true where id =?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class ItemListing {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="item")
    private List<ItemSales> sales;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public List<ItemSales> getSales() {
        return sales;
    }
    public void setSales(List<ItemSales> sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }   
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }
    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
    
}
```

---

Comment: try this `create.multiselect(builder.sum(root.get(array[0])), builder.sum(root.get(array[1)));`

Comment: This I have to specify the number of values I am passing I need I may send any number of column names, but query need to build according according to the number of column name dynamically.

Comment: you can try this `public List<Selection<?>> getColumns(List<String> keys, Root<?> root) {
  return keys.stream().map(root::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }`

Comment: @AbrarAnsari  I don't know how to implement this method for Criteria Query. Can you please implement and post an answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional
public List<Tuple> multiColumn(String column) {
    ItemListing item = new ItemListing();
    item.setName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    item.setPrice(10.50);
    item.setQuantity(20);

    //dummy data for testing
    entityManager.persist(item);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(column);
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("column");

    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> create = builder.createTupleQuery();
    Root<ItemListing> root = create.from(ItemListing.class);
    create.multiselect(getColumns(array, root, builder));
    TypedQuery<Tuple> query = entityManager.createQuery(create);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<Selection<?>> getColumns(JSONArray keys, Root<?> root, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    return keys.toList().stream().map(entry -> builder.sum(root.get(entry.toString())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

you can read the result like below

List result = runner.multiColumn("{"column":["price", "quantity"]}");
result.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x.get(0) + "::" + x.get(1)));

Comment: No it is not working bro. I am getting this error    No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.persistence.criteria.Root .

Comment: can you share your `ItemListing` class?

Comment: I have updated the question with ItemListing class bro.